# Fluent Nhibernate Component Prefix

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to set the column prefix for a component in fluent. For example:

```
public class SomeClassMap : ClassMap < SomeClass >
{

    public SomeClassMap()
    {
        CreateMap();
    }

    private void CreateMap()
    {
        WithTable("Class");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Name).WithLengthOf(100);

        Component<SomeComponent>(x => x.somecomponent, m =>
        {
            m.Map(x => x.Name).SetAttribute("column", "SomeComponentName");
            m.Map(x => x.Summary).SetAttribute("column", "SomeComponentSummary");
            .... etc ...
        }
     );
```

Is there a way to set "SomeComponent" prefixes instead of having to define them in a SetAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing implicit. AutoMapping does it, but not regular mapping. I've created [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/issues/detail?id=247) so you can track the status of this.

Comment: The correct project site is http://fluentnhibernate.org. That link was to a ticket which no longer exists, not to the project itself.

Comment: BTW James, the Component Prefix is broken: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287698/fluentnhibernate-component-columnprefix-not-being-applied/6727557

Answer (score 1):

There is some good information here: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-2-value-objects.aspx that seems to be what you are wanting to do.

In particular the Action method demonstrated in this sample:

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    private Action<ComponentPart<Address>> MapAddress(string columnPrefix)
    {
        return a =>
               {
                   a.Map(x => x.AddressLine1, columnPrefix + "AddressLine1");
                   a.Map(x => x.AddressLine2, columnPrefix + "AddressLine2");
                   a.Map(x => x.PostalCode, columnPrefix + "PostalCode");
                   a.Map(x => x.City, columnPrefix + "City");
                   a.Map(x => x.Country, columnPrefix + "Country");
               };
}

public EmployeeMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.FirstName).CanNotBeNull().WithLengthOf(20);
    Map(x => x.LastName).CanNotBeNull().WithLengthOf(20);

    Component<Address>(x => x.HomeAddress, MapAddress("Home_"));
    Component<Address>(x => x.WorkAddress, MapAddress("Work_"));
}
```

}