# FluentNHibernate Component.ColumnPrefix not being applied

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I recently upgraded **FluentNHibernate** from **v1.1.0.685** to **v1.2.0.712** (latest) for **NHibernate 2.1**.

My issue appears to be with classes that use the `Component().ColumnPrefix()` mapping.

For example,

```
 public class Address{ 
    public string Street {get; set;} 
    public string Zip {get; set;} 
 } 

 public class AddressMap : ComponentMap<Address>{
     Map( x => x.Street );
     Map( x => x.Zip );
 }

 public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person> 
 { 
    public PersonMap(){ 

       Id( x => x.Id ); 

       Map( x=> x.Name ); 

       Component( x => x.Address ) 
          .ColumnPrefix("ADDRESS_"); 
    } 
 }
```

*Person Table*

```
  Id       Name        ADDRESS_Street     ADDRESS_Zip
 ----------------------------------------------------
  1        Brian       123 Example St.    12345
```

#### Behavior in FNH v1.1.0.685

The **"ADDRESS_"** prefix is *correctly* applied to the properties of the Address component.

#### Behavior in FNH v1.2.0.712 (latest)

The **"ADDRESS_"** prefix is *no longer* applied to the properties of the Address component. **NHiberante** generates "**Street**" and "**Zip**" columns which are not named in table above.

---

I'd appreciate if anyone has any insight. I'm beginning to think this *might* be a bug.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the unit tests in the source code; it appears that, in my case, my conventions were being applied differently between **FNH v1.1** and **FNH v1.2**.

I think this is what happened:

1. My `AddressMap : ComponentMap<Address>` would get executed (no problem here).
2. My `PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>` would map a component using:

   ```
   Component( x => x.Address ).ColumnPrefix("ADDRESS_");
   ```

   from Step 1.
3. My **FNH** `MyPropertyConvention` would call:

   ```
   public class MyPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention
   {
       public void Apply( IPropertyInstance instance )
       {
           instance.Column( instance.Name ); //this call is destructive
                                             //to ColumnPrefix() in FNH v1.2
       }
   }
   ```

**It appears:**

- in **FNH v1.1**, Step 3 is *not destructive* to the column prefix when calling `instance.Column()`.
- in **FNH v1.2**, Step 3 is *destructive* to any `ColumnPrefix()` previously set and over-writes the *entire* column name (including the prefix).

So, I cleaned up my conventions for **FNH 1.2** using `IPropertyConventionAcceptance` being careful about my calls to `instance.Column(instance.Name)` [now that calls are destructive to column prefixes].

Thanks for everyone's help,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

@Brian,

I hit the exact roadblock a few weeks ago. I'm using automappings and got around it by creating a Component Property Convention:

```
Public Class ComponentPropertyConvention
    Implements IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance

    Public Sub Accept(ByVal criteria As IAcceptanceCriteria(Of IPropertyInspector)) Implements IConventionAcceptance(Of IPropertyInspector).Accept
       criteria.Expect(Function(inspector) inspector.EntityType.Namespace.EndsWith("Components"))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Apply(ByVal instance As IPropertyInstance) Implements IConvention(Of IPropertyInspector, IPropertyInstance).Apply
        instance.Column(String.Format("{0}_{1}", New String() {instance.EntityType.Name.ToLower(), instance.Property.Name.Dbize()}))
    End Sub

End Class
```

There's probably a wealth of ways to implement your acceptance criteria so don't follow mine if it doesnt suit...

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to get one of the maintainers to FIX the issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `ComponentMap<Address>` class in order for the `ColumnPrefix` to be applied.

See here: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#ComponentMap.3CT.3E

Comment: Hi Variant, I checked my code, and indeed, I do have a `ComponentMap<Address>` and it's still not recognizing the prefix column. I've updated my question to include the `ComponentMap<Address>`